# Select set standard value

Tags: php, html, laravel

```
<select class="form-control" id="package_id" name="package_id">
    @foreach($packages as $package)
        <option value="{{$package->id}}">{{$package->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Is there a way to set the "initial" value before selecting it?
Standard its the first option but is there a way to set it too the second or third one?

Comment: Select which default value you want from the `options` and add the attribute `selected="selected"`

Answer (score 0):

the `<option>` HTML tag has an attribute called `selected` you can set on an option to have it be selected by default. You can use the PHP ternary statement to decide when to assign it.

```
@foreach($packages as $package)
    <option value="{{$package->id}}" {{ $package->selected ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{$package->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Replace `$package->selected` with whatever logic you want to use to choose which option is selected, it needs to evaluate to a boolean.